# Unexpected figure rotation

Tags: rotating

I have some images embebed  in pdf file. 
Same formula/coding but some image rotated auto (wrong) and some image are correct. Image file: jpg.

My minimal coding:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=0.5cm,right=5.0cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig,floatrow}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tikzsymbols} 

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt,minmargin=0cm, maxmargin=0cm,justification=centering}
{ \begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=0,rotate=0]{"example-image-a"}

\\
\textcolor{red}{Name}
\end{center}
}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

I think maybe: images rotated auto when height > width of image.

I added “rotate = 0, angle = 0” into code, but no effect.

Please help.

Thank in advance

Comment: TeX won't rotate them automatically... Just saying. What type of images are you including? Could you have them auto-rotated in some other package and it was saved rotated?

Comment: @Werner thanks. My image files type: jpg. Some images jpg rotated auto and others jpg not . Same coding, same width but different height

Comment: My all package : \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,scalerel}
\usepackage{pgffor, ifthen} \usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} \usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage{ifthen} \usepackage[utf8]{english}\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}\usepakage{tikzsymbols}\usepackage{ragged2e}\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}\usetikzlibrry{decorations.text, arrows.meta,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}%\usepackage[format=plain,      %    abelfont={bf,it},

Comment: and:  %   textfont=it]{caption}\usepackage{caption}         %\usepackage{adjustbox}\usepackage{bbding}\usepackage{subfigure}\usepackae{wrapfig,floatrow}\usepackage{pifont}\input{insbox}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={mymap(\x)=int(mod(1+\x*\x,4));}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{atbegshi}% 
%\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

Comment: and: \usepackage{translator, tikz, array} % pgfcalendar loaded later with
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{datatool,xfp}
\usepackage{filecontents}

Comment: `angle=0` and `rotate =0` are not options of `\includegraphics`. You will find the options applicable to this command in the `graphicx` package manual here: http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf

Comment: Edit your question (by clicking on the `edit` button) instead of answering in the comments.

Comment: I had the same problem, but then I opened my images using gimp (OS Ubuntu) and realized that my images were rotated. So they were not being rotated by Latex.

Answer (score 4):

Provided you have access to the `graphicx` package (which is being loaded by `tikzsymbols` in your case), you can use the `angle=` key to specify the rotation angle of the graphic. No `rotate=` key exists:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[angle=90, width=2cm]{"example-image-a"}
\end{center}
```

Note that the keys are read from left to right, so the above code rotates the image by 90 degrees anticlockwise and *then* scales the image to have a width of `2cm`. Compare the two images produced by

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[angle=90, width=2cm]{"example-image-a"}First
\includegraphics[width=2cm, angle=90]{"example-image-a"}Second
\end{center}
```

[image: output]

The second was reduced to a width of `2cm` before being rotated (so that its *height* is now `2cm`).

Comment: Thank for your reply. In my case, i don't want unexpected Rotation when Height of image (2.5cm) > Width of image (2.cm). What should I edit?

Comment: Remove the `angle=90` or use `angle=0` for no rotation.

Comment: i changed angle but not unsuccess. But luckly when i save as file A.JPG (caption) to  A.jpg then done. :). Thank so much.